# Fill in Missing Values Of A Categorical Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill in some missing categorical values of a column. I have 2 columns. One is categorical and one is not. If a value is missing in the categorical column, I want to assign a value to it based on the categorical value that has the largest number of counts.

My columns look like this:

```
School_Assigned    Will_You_Enroll_There

Anderson           Yes
Williams           No
Anderson           NaN
Anderson           Yes
Anderson           Maybe
```

Based on this, the NaN value should contain Yes since the number of Yes's (for Anderson) are greater than the number of no's and maybe's. School_Assigned and Will_You_Enroll_There are columns 10 and 11 respectively. My data frame is called gt_Exam.

Here is my code:

```
enroll_categories = ["Yes", "No", "Maybe"]
count1 = 0
count2 = 0
count3 = 0

for i in range(len(gt_Exam)):

    if pd.isna(gt_Exam.iloc[i, 11]) == True:

        value = gt_Exam.iloc[i, 10]

        for j in range(len(gt_Exam)):

            if (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 10] == value) & (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 11] == enroll_categories[0]):

                count1 += 1

            elif (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 10] == value) & (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 11] == enroll_categories[1]):

                count2 += 1

            elif (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 10] == value) & (gt_Exam.iloc[j, 11] == enroll_categories[2]):

                count3 += 1

        maximum_categories = max(count1, count2, count3)

        if maximum_categories == count1:

            gt_Exam.iloc[i, 11] = enroll_categories[0]

        elif maximum_categories == count2:

            gt_Exam.iloc[i, 11] = enroll_categories[1]

        else:

            gt_Exam.iloc[i, 11] = enroll_categories[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the first [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) per group ([`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html)):

```
gt_Exam['Will_You_Enroll_There'] = gt_Exam['Will_You_Enroll_There'].fillna(
    gt_Exam.groupby('School_Assigned')['Will_You_Enroll_There']
        .transform(lambda s: pd.Series.mode(s)[0])
)
```

[`Series.get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) can be used if it is possible a group is all `NaN` and, thus, produces no mode. This will prevent a key error and also (optionally) allow a default value to be specified:

```
gt_Exam['Will_You_Enroll_There'] = gt_Exam['Will_You_Enroll_There'].fillna(
    gt_Exam.groupby('School_Assigned')['Will_You_Enroll_There']
        .transform(lambda s: pd.Series.mode(s).get(0))
)
```

`gt_Exam`:

```
  School_Assigned Will_You_Enroll_There
0        Anderson                   Yes
1        Williams                    No
2        Anderson                   Yes
3        Anderson                   Yes
4        Anderson                 Maybe
```

---

DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

gt_Exam = pd.DataFrame({
    'School_Assigned': {0: 'Anderson', 1: 'Williams', 2: 'Anderson',
                        3: 'Anderson', 4: 'Anderson'},
    'Will_You_Enroll_There': {0: 'Yes', 1: 'No', 2: np.nan, 3: 'Yes',
                              4: 'Maybe'}
})
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting a KeyError: 0

Comment: Is it possible you have groups that are all NaN?

Comment: Yes, they are there.

Comment: You can try `get(0)` instead of `[0]` take a look at the edit.

Comment: Perfect!! Worked Smoothly! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Glad to figure out cleaner ways of dealing with data instead of clumsy ways in my quest to becoming a Data Scientist!